# Why is Craft rendering a blank page instead of an error template?

Tags: error-templates

I'm currently seeing this in the PHP error logs:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Craft\\HttpException' with message '' in
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59\nStack
> trace:\n#0 (): Craft\\TemplatesController->actionRender()\n#1
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(109):
> ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()\n#2
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47):
> CAction->runWithParamsInternal()\n#3
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308):
> CInlineAction->runWithParams()\n#4
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286):
> CController->runAction()\n#5
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265):
> CController->runActionWithFilters()\n#6
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(284):
> CController->run()\n#7
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141):
> CWebApplication->runController()\n#8
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(288):
> CWebApplication->processRequest()\n#9
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185):
> Craft\\WebApp->processRequest()\n#10
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/craft/app/index.php(62):
> CApplication->run()\n#11
> /home/vagrant/htdocs/site/public/index.php(19): include()\n#12 {main}
> ```

I have a `_404.html` template under `templates/` and the `errorTemplatePrefix` set to `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was HHVM causing the issue. Switching back to 'normal' PHP made the problem disappear.